# Why does Blend-Exchange say my file is not a blend file?

Tags: support

When I upload my Blender file Blend-Exchange I get a message saying my file is not a blend file. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/GiantCowFilms/Blend-Exchange/issues/56, which has now been resolved. I apologize for the slow response in getting this addressed.

Comment: You are awesome! People like you make the world a better place. Much gratitude!

Answer (score 5):

Where did you upload?  That looks like [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/).  If it is, you have probably tried to upload a compressed 3.x file.  For some reason, blend-exchange sometimes doesn't recognize the new compression algorithm.  Try uploading without compression.

Comment: Probably compression is not the only one reason ... I tried several 3.1 without compression now, with this error ... https://imgur.com/2CfdBdh

Comment: I have been experiencing the same `internal error` every time I try to upload recently. For now, we can use [PasteAll](https://pasteall.org/blend/), but it's only temporary hosting (about 5 months). Hopefully @GiantCowFilms will be able to resolve it soon. Our community really benefits from Blend Exchange.

Comment: @Mentalist Issue is now fixed, I apologize for how long this took to be addressed... my (multiple :( ) jobs are quite demanding right now.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms You are doing this community an incredible service.  You never need to apologize for how long it takes you to cope with changes in Blender's implementation.